# How to get a symmetric positive definite 5x5 matrix?

Tags: matrices

\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
is an example.
But I don't find another one. There also should be entries other than 0 or 1.

Is there a systematic way to do this?

Comment: See http://www.mat.uc.pt/~cmf/papers/tri_positive_definite_revisited.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any invertible matrix $A$ (so just about any matrix unless you're unlucky) and compute $A^TA$.

It is easy to check that $(A^TA)^T=A^T(A^T)^T=A^TA$ (symetric), and for all $x$

$x^T(A^TA)x = (x^T A^T)(Ax)= (Ax)^T(Ax) = (Ax) \cdot (Ax) = \|Ax\|^2\geq 0$ (positive).

Plus since $A$ is invertible, this is equal to $0$ if and only if $x=0$. (definite)

Therefore $A^TA$ is symmetric definite positive.

Comment: @g-h-faust : thanks for the edit, I forgot a couple of T's indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Choose any 5 strictly positive numbers and form a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$.

Now take any orthogonal $5 \times 5$ matrix $U$, and form the product $A=U \Lambda U^T$. It is straightforward to check that $A>0$ and $A^T = A$.

(Note that for **any** $A$ satisfying  $A>0$ and $A=A^T$, then it can be written in the form $A=U \Lambda U^T$.)

Answer (score 3):

Replace all non-diagonal entries symmetrically and randomly with numbers whose absolute values are smaller than $\frac14$. By [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), all eigenvalues of the result random matrix will fall inside a circle of radius smaller than $1$ centered at $1$. Since the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are real, the eigenvalues will be all positive. i.e. Any random matrix generated in this manner will be positive definite.

Comment: this worked for me fastest. thank you, and to all others thank you, too!

Comment: Why less than 1/4 and does this work for higher-dimensional matrices?

Comment: @dtn For $n \times n$ matrices, replace $\frac14$ by $\frac{1}{n-1}$. The radii of those circles in Gershogrin circle theorem are the sum of the absolute values of the non-diagonal entries in corresponding row) If the magnitude of all non-diagonal entries are strictly less than $\frac1{n-1}$, the radii of the circles will be strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Why should the radius be set to 1? It is necessary to extend the radius to the entire positive half-plane, and thus take into account the element lying on the diagonals in the corresponding row of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way, particularly useful for generating SPD matrices with constant diagonal entries, is to take $A=\alpha I+B$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $B$ is any symmetric matrix with $\rho(B)=\|B\|<\alpha$ (can be done simply by taking an arbitrary symmetric matrix and scaling it such that the inequality holds).

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about the matrix scaling procedure?